# android sliding drawer hiding icons after while

Tags: android

I use a drawer with "Open and Close with the App Icon" from this doc:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

The problem is, that if I open and close the drawer a few times it happens that no icons come up again, expect the overflow icon and its entries. It seems to happen by chance, no matter if I click on the button or slide it in. It only happens with my tablet where all icons are on top. 
I have no clue what this problem is.
thanks for any help or ideas where to investigate.

Comment: What icons do you mean? Inside the `NavigationDrawer` or the `ActionBar` icons or? Maybe you could supply a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: the action bar icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not longer happening any longer